# How to export the difference between two workspace folders in linux/Shellscript?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Hi iam using the following command `diff --brief -lr` to find the differences between two folders .Containing different folders and files.I want to export the differences .

Please suggest a solution as i am new to shell script.???

Comment: You can save command output by doing redirection: `command > file.txt`

Comment: Why not just redirect the output to a file (ie " diff --brief -lr  > diffs.txt")

Answer (score 1):

To save command output to a file:

```
diff --brief -lr > file.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,
but if i want to copy the file which have the difference then what should I do
for eg. /home/dushyant/CUST/customer.js and /home/dushyant/Cust2/customer.js ,if i comparing two .JS file and if the difference is found ,then i could copy the customer.js file of folder Cust2 in any other location.